# separate node.exe for each Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

In my Azure function app, there are 10 functions. and when an error happens in a function which result in node exit with code=-1. then all of the functions get stopped to work. so is there any solution to handle this? is it possible to assign every function a separated node.exe?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to control how the worker processes are spawned. The only other way that I could think of to workaround this problem is to have separate function apps.

As for the crashing part, there seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/180) addressing this which could remove the need for multiple workers.